# prolog logic and cut

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

I have a some problem understaing the flow of prolog. here is the code:

```
h(X):- 1 is X mod 2, write(X), nl, 0 is X mod 3, !, fail.
h(_).
t(_,[],0).
t(M,[_|LS],1):-member(M,LS),write('member'), nl,fail.
t(_,[H|_],H).
r([X|LS],R):-h(X), M is 2*X+1,t(M, LS, R), write(R), nl, fail.
```

now I am runing 3 things:
1. r([3,7,9],R).
2. r([5,11,13],R).
3. r([2,3,5],R).
 and I cant understand the answers I get.
the answers are:
1. 3
   false.
2. 5
   11
  false.
3. member
3
   false.

hope for help!

Comment: What answers were you expecting? Note that a cut followed by `fail` results in "false" since the cut eliminates backtracking. Therefore, in your definition of `h/1`, if `1 is X mod 2` and `0 is X mod 3` succeed, then `h(X)` will necessarily fail, and then `h(X), M is 2*X + 1, ...` won't ever get past the `h(X)` query. It's unclear to me why you'd want to use `!, fail` in `h/1` at all. It's a very poor way to enforce conditions for a predicate clause to be applicable or not.

Comment: thank you. 
it is a question from an exam actually.
I really dont get the use of the cut here.. 
in r([5,11,13],R).  why do I get 11 at all?

Comment: Have you done any reading about how Prolog works? Have you tried doing a `trace.` and then running the queries to see what the code does? Before doing the `trace` it's good to understand the meaning of *backtracking* and how that's a basic Prolog behavior.

Comment: thank you.
what I have trouble understanding is why do we get 11..and not member . h(X) is satisfied with X=5 and 5 is printed, then we continue with t(11,[11,13],R) and we get into the second role, so I cant understand why are we printing 11 and why not printing member?

Comment: Because you have `t(M,[_|LS],1) :- member(M,LS),write('member'), ...`, so  `t(11, [11,13], R) :- ...` is checking `member(11, [13])` which fails.

Comment: ohh right.
thanks a lot